# How to assert text of a span class?

Tags: dalekjs

We have a block structure like this below and we like to check for Welcome (abc_site) text.
But we cant seem to capture it.
Dalekjs keeps saying Found Object object

```
<div id="login" style="display: block;">
            <span class="simple-resource-header" id="welcomeText">Welcome <i>(abc_site)</i></span>
            <button type="submit" id="submitButton" onclick="out();">Out</button>
</div>
```

How do we assert this properly ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the script you wrote for this?

Answer (score 0):

Save your HTML markup into `test.html`, expose it on a web server and try the following dalek test file:

```
module.exports = {

  'Welcome page': function (test) {
    test
      .open('.../test.html')
      .assert.text('#welcomeText').is('Welcome (abc_site)', 'shows the welcome text')
      .done();
  }

};
```